# Keep two-colored text blocks in EditText while editing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to create an `EditText` with two blocks of text with different colors:

```
String strText = txtEditText.getText().toString();
String strFrontPart = strText.substring(0, FRONT_PART_COUNT);
String strBackPart = strText.substring(FRONT_PART_COUNT);
String text = "<font color=#ffffff>" + strFrontPart + "</font>";
text += "<font color=#000000>" + strBackPart + "</font>";
txtEditText.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

The code above successfully converts `FRONT_PART_COUNT` characters at the front to white characters and the rest to black.

My question is ***how do I achieve this while editing EditText?***

I can't obviously put this in `afterTextChanged()` because it will cause an infinite recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mBugDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bug_description);
    mWhiteSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFFFF);
    mBlackSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFF000000);

    mBugDescription.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(s.length() > 0) {
                int FRONT_PART_COUNT = 10;

                s.setSpan(mWhiteSpan, 0, Math.min(s.length(), FRONT_PART_COUNT), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                if(s.length() > FRONT_PART_COUNT){
                    s.setSpan(mBlackSpan, FRONT_PART_COUNT + 1, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to put this together.

Comment: but are you sure it's `FRONT_PART_COUNT + 1` in the line for setting the black color?

Comment: which means you can put 1 instead of 0 in the line for setting the white color?

Comment: ok, now I understand the gap between our understanding. so the second and third parameters of `setSpan()` are rather start and end indexes, NOT start and count... so changing them to `FRONT_PART_COUNT - 1` and `FRONT_PART_COUNT` will be more logical right?

Comment: in my created sample +1 worked for me the first ten characters were colored in white and rest of characters were colored black didn't test without +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `setSpan` method of `Editable` param in `afterTextChanged` handler.

Sample:

```
EditText editText
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    final ForegroundColorSpan red = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));

    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        int max = 2;
        if(s.length() < max) max = s.length();
        s.setSpan(red, 0, max, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
    }
});
```

First two letters will be red.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, using a `TextWatcher` would be the best idea (specifically, the `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` method), as it can execute modifications upon the text after being edited in the `EditText`.

Then you can just add it by passing it as a parameter in `txtEditText.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher t)`.

More info on `TextWatcher`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Comment: you have not obviously read the question, and copy/pasted another SO answer haven't you...

Comment: I did read the question. I just decided to give you pointers in the documentation instead of giving you a copy/paste answer. Not the most effective or pleasant, that's right, but we both could learn from this :)

Comment: well, if you read the question, you must have seen this line -- ***I can't obviously put this in afterTextChanged()...*** -- which means I have tried it already and don't need the documentation... ;)

Comment: god, my eyes were failing me. You were right! sorry!
but then again, why haven't you tried with **onTextChanged()**?

Comment: `setText()` triggers all three `TextWatcher` events -- `onTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged`, that's why it will be an infinite recursive call.